# React how to use the state in a "useEffect" with socket.io

Tags: reactjs, socket.io, react-hooks, use-effect

I have this code

```
  const [magicValue, setMagicValue] = useState([]) // assume that the value is now ["1"]
  
  useEffect(() => {
    const socket = socketIOClient(ENDPOINT)
    socket.on("webhook", (data) => {
      console.log(magicValue) // this will always be []
    })
  }, [])
```

The problem is that I seem to always have the magicValue as [] even if the state ["1"]. I even create a button to log that indeed the state is updated to ["1"], but for some reason, in the useEffect I get []

Comment: Does changing your `useEffect` capture to `[magicValue]` fix the problem? I don't think this has anything to do with socket.io, although this isn't quite a [mcve].

Comment: Does this answer your question? [useState set method not reflecting change immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54069253/usestate-set-method-not-reflecting-change-immediately)

Comment: replacing [] with magicValue work. tnx

Comment: using magicValue as a dependency for the useEffect will cause the event handler to be recreated each time magicValue changes. If magicValue is changing often you might need to look at a different approach.

Comment: Yeah, that's a good point--there's probably not much sense in putting a `socket.on` inside `useEffect` in most cases.